# UIActionSheet Cancel button keeps crashing my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am really puzzeled by this one. I have set up two UIActionSheets in my application. They work perfectly fine until you use the cancel button in the UIActionSheets.

When i navigate away from the page the UIAactionSheet returns too it crashes my app.

Does anyone have any ideas as too why?

```
-(IBAction) phoneButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
// open a dialog with just an OK button
phoneActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Phone: %@",phone],nil];
phoneActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[phoneActionSheet showInView:self.view];    // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
[phoneActionSheet release]; 
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (actionSheet == phoneActionSheet) {

    if(buttonIndex == 0){
            NSString *callPhone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone];
            NSLog(@"Calling: %@", callPhone);
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callPhone]];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Does anything get logged to the console when your app crashes? If so, posting the message would help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not releasing the phoneActionSheet in phoneButtonClicked.  I suspect you might be trying to do something with a bad pointer.  Another good help is to use [NSZombieEnabled](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

Comment: Nothing was logged in the console but removing the release command worked.

Comment: The sheet probably leaks without that release.  Each time, you invoke phoneButtonClicked, you create a new sheet that you are no longer releasing.  However, you need to release it after the sheet has been dismissed, not straight after it has been created.

Comment: I typically release the action sheets in the clickedButton and/or canceled call.  This isn't the best, but it keeps their lifetimes short.